# add a simple bibliography in beamer (using texmaker)

Tags: beamer, bibliographies

I want to add a simple bibliography in my beamer presentation like this 
http://recherche.noiraudes.net/images/screenshots/Beamer1.jpg .

In an article, it is easy but i couldnt do the same in my presentation. Can someone help me with a simple example please?knowing that my bibliography contains 4 references (in a single slide, i need to add 2 references).
Thank you by advance

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.